# Can't upgrade to 18.04 from 17.10

Tags: upgrade, lts, do-release-upgrade

I cannot update to 18.04 from 17.10 installation. Neither

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

or (I am using Wayland)

```
xhost +
sudo xhost si:localuser:root
sudo update-manager -cd
```

worked for me. I got

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Upgrades to the development release are only 
available from the latest supported release.
```

in the first case and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwqVt.png) in the second. What else could I do?

Comment: What happens if you drop the `-d` ? 18.04 Bionic Beaver isn't development any more. 18.10 Cosmic Cuttlefish should be current development version.

Comment: @SorenA this   `Checking for a new Ubuntu release` and then `No new release found.`

Comment: So, in the end I used [debian way](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-upgrade-to-ubuntu-18-04-lts-bionic-beaver#h9-how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-the-debian-way).

Answer (score 2):

From **Software & Updates** program open **Updates** tab
then from option **Notify me of a new Ubuntu version** select **For any new 
version**
[image: Software & Updates screenshoot]

Then enter in terminal:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Comment: @user535733 you're right, I edited it

Comment: doesn't work for me. Got `No new release found`.

Answer (score -1):

`do-release-upgrade` works for the first minor version after LTS release, thus:

July 26th

Ubuntu Ubuntu 18.04.1

has to be available.

[BB Release Schedule](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseSchedule)

Comment: Upgrade to 18.04 from 17.10 is already supported as 17.10 is *not* an LTS release. Upgrade from older LTS releases would be available after the release of first point release (18.04.1) as you've mentioned.

Comment: no, `do-release-upgrade` doesn't work for me