# How to upgrade Ubuntu 16.04.2 to 16.04.3

Tags: upgrade, do-release-upgrade

I've read this link: [How to upgrade Ubuntu to specific version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1020218/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-to-specific-version?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), but I still don't know how to upgrade my system from 16.04.2 to 16.04.3.

Comment: Looks strange. If you ran regular `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` you will already have 16.04.4 LTS (since [1 march 2018](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases)). Do you have any errors on `sudo apt-get update`?

Comment: @N0rbert   I don't need 16.04.4, I need 16.04.3.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to update the system, no needed to upgrade
Recommended to upgrade to newest **stable** version 
this may help you to upgrade: [How To Upgrade Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1046180/cant-upgrade-to-18-04-from-17-10/1046181#1046181)

to check the start and end of support for each version [Ubuntu release end of life](https://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life)